# Cómo pasar parámetros desde C# a C++

Tags: c#, c++

Al momento de ejecutar la llamada desde C# sale el error de system.accessviolationexception. ¿Por qué ocurre y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Código en C#:

```
private const string DllFilePath = @"\\Controles\gesqlib.dll";

[DllImport(DllFilePath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static int LeerIDSecuenciaEnIncr(int a, char[] ruta,out int b);

public static void getIncrementID()
{
    try
    {
        string pathFile = @"\\pesdaw019.per.e-corpnet.org\PRO_Esquemas\Gest_edi\Esquemas\EDELNOR.gesq";
        int inc = 0;

        char[] myChar = pathFile.ToCharArray();
         LeerIDSecuenciaEnIncr(1, myChar,out inc);
         MessageBox.Show("RESULT= " + inc, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Método en C++:

```
int LeerIDSecuenciaEnIncr(UARHANDLE* uarHandle, char* lpszPathIncr, LONG* lIdSecuencia)
    {
    int iRet = 0;
    int iCanal;

    *lIdSecuencia = -1;

    for (iCanal = 0; iCanal <= _MAXCANAL; iCanal++)
    {
        if (UARopen(uarHandle, lpszPathIncr, iCanal))                /* Abre el fichero incremental */
            break;
    }

    if (iCanal > _MAXCANAL)
        return 0;   // No se puede abrir el esquema

    if (PasarContenidoGinc(uarHandle, iCanal))
    {
        LONG pos = UARtell(uarHandle, iCanal) + sizeof(IEDISC); // porque UARtell resta sizeof(IEDISC)
        LONG fileLength = UARfilelength(uarHandle, iCanal);

        iRet = -1;                                                  // de momento decimos que no tiene ID de secuencia
        if (pos != fileLength)                                  // si tiene ID de secuencia...
        {
            *lIdSecuencia = UARrdlong(uarHandle, iCanal);               // leemos el ID de secuencia

            pos = UARtell(uarHandle, iCanal) + sizeof(IEDISC);      // porque UARtell resta sizeof(IEDISC)

            iRet = 1;                                               // de momento decimos que tiene un sólo ID de secuencia
            if (pos != fileLength)                              // si hay más de un ID de secuencia...
            {
                // hay más de un ID de secuencia añadido al final del ginc y no sabemos cual es el bueno
                *lIdSecuencia = -1;
                iRet = -2;
            }
        }
    }

    UARclose(uarHandle, iCanal);

    return iRet;
}
```